# This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

ALready downloaded the sqlsrv on microsoft...

[image]

and on my phpinfo()

[image]

[image]

enabled on `php.ini` on both `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin` and `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`
[image]

and still got error like this.

```
Failed to get DB handle: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
```

and my code is

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$db","$user","$pass");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select top 5 from teams");
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
  unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
```

Comment: "driver 11". did you check which version you actually have installed? just having an sqlserver driver means nothing.

Comment: @MarcB what do you mean? where to check it?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Apart of the `pdo_sqlsrv` extension, you also need to have the ODBC 11 driver installed on your machine.

You can get it at one of these locations:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you for saving me heheheh

Comment: One important thing to note; although the error message indicates that you need x86 drivers; you MUST install x64 if your server is x64. Otherwise you won't be able to install as it will say "this driver is not compatible with you system". And anyways, x64 driver already includes x86.

Comment: It is worth noting that **sqlserv** in the extensions list is not the ODBC. That confused me a bit.

Comment: If this is an ODBC driver, do we even need the sqlsrv extensions enabled?

Comment: Having sqlsrv, why should I need ODBC, no explanations anywhere, why do I need a binary blob? and how do I get it for a vanilla Linux distro, (not listed) What happened to tarballs and make commands as the standard?

Comment: Yes ohhh the pleasure.... FINALLY able to connect php laravel application with mssql is sooooo good. It just took me 2 days to figure it out. Thx alot brother

Comment: Double check versions of drivers to be sure that they can work together.Check if you use good version of ODBC Drivers to work with PHP sqlsrv.