# How to connect a cloud mssql db from xampp?

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to connect a cloud mssql server from my xampp localhost using pdo?
How to do that?

```
try {
    $hostname = "xxxxxx";
    $dbname = "xxxxxx";
    $username = "xxxxxxx";
    $pw = "xxxxxxx";
    $dbh = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
```

it gives error  Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver

i dont know any other information about the db...only i know is that it is a cloud mssql database...pls help me in this

my localhost php version is 5.6.31
i am using xampp in windows 7

Comment: Maybe the odbc driver is available, the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) says that also should work. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105561/3783243

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126338/xampp-ms-sql-server-php-5-6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401170/this-extension-requires-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-11-for-sql-server-to-communica this two link solved my problem